# Confidence intervals and sample size

Tags: statistics

Are confidence intervals wider if sample size is larger? Similarly are confidence intervals narrower if sample size is smaller?

Comment: Larger sample size leads to narrower confidence interval.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a specific example. Suppose you have $n$ independent observations $X_i$ from $N(\mu, \sigma_0^2),$ where you want
a 95% confidence interval (CI) for unknown $\mu$. Also suppose
$\sigma_0^2$ is known, and denote the mean of the observations
as $\bar X.$

Then the confidence interval is $\bar X \pm 1.96\sigma_0/\sqrt{n}.$
The 'margin of error' of this CI is $1.96\sigma_0/\sqrt{n}$
and its total width is twice the margin of error.

For simplicity, suppose $\sigma_0 = 1.$ First, let $n = 4.$ Then the margin of error is
$1.96/2 \approx 1$. But if we increase the sample size to
$n = 16$, then the margin of error is $1.96/4 \approx 1/2.$

For some situations the math is a little less obvious, but this same relationship holds in almost all practical situations.
Very roughly, the idea is that more data gives more information
and that means we can more precisely estimate $\mu.$ The smaller
the margin of error the more precise the estimate.